# Редирект с "site.loc/?" на "site.loc/"

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать редирект с страницы "site.loc/?" на "site.loc", будет огромным плюсов если это будет работать на всех страницах, то есть "site.loc/page/?". Подойдет решение и на PHP. Все работает под управлением CMS WordPress.

Пробовал сделать с помощью

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ /
```

Проверял отдельно на [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be) и работает для главной страницы. Но как только добавляю уже до рабочего файла, который выглядит вот так:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

То перестает работать, если в конец файла разместить. Если разместить в начале файла, начинается циклический редирект.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно убрать пустой вопрос то решение вот:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^.+ .+\? "
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

Тут приходится делать две странные вещи:

1. Искать вопрос в конце URI в переменной `THE_REQUEST`. Дело в том что эта перемнная разделяется в дальнейшем на `REQUEST_METHOD`, `REQUEST_URI`, `QUERY_STRING` и `SERVER_PROTOCOL`. При этом "вопрос" теряется. То есть его нету ни в `REQUEST_URI` ни в `QUERY_STRING`;
2. Подставлять вопрос в `RewriteRule` чтобы вопрос убрать (ну вот так это работает)

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Вот только для главной страницы, ну и на этом уже очень хорошо. Дальше уже с помощью JavaScripta добить можно.

Comment: @БогданЛесько Почему только для главной? Должно работать со всеми. Можете привести пример с которым не работает?

Comment: вот можете [глянуть](https://seo.vallaskes.com.ua/zakazat-semanticheskoe-yadro/?)

Comment: или может я тупанул где-то

вот так сейчас

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^.+ .+\? "
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R]
</IfModule>


когда розмещал после кода вордпреса то никаких изменений небыло

Comment: Поднимите два правила выше (RewriteCond + RewriteRule). Сразу после RewriteBase

Comment: Если сразу после RewriteBase / выдает 302 ошибку. Можете перейти по прошлой ссылке увидете.

Comment: Кто выдает? 302 - это код редиректа. Если надо 301, нужно поменять `[R]` на `[R=301]`

Comment: Показывает уже страницу с ошибкой "301 Moved Permanently" заменил вот это RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301]

Comment: Вот это да. Как-то интересно у вас апач настроен что он редиректы как ошибки показывает

Comment: Из ответа куда-то девается заголовок Location. Такое ощущение что nginx не отдает этот заголовок

Comment: стандартные настройки на хостинге, хостинг Ukraine

Comment: А их хотя бы увидеть можно? proxy_redirect off нету случайно? Или proxy_hide_header

Comment: Похоже у вас проявляется вот этот баг https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1381 Если ввести адрес http://seo.vallaskes.com.ua/zakazat-semanticheskoe-yadro/? (то есть без HTTPS) то редирект работает нормально

Comment: не нашел этих настроек, вот 1 скрин [настроек](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8pvUPwZ4qWPvdPhMA) и [второй что у них есть](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8FF2xbTHyriSPUxe8)

Comment: Образайтесь к хостеру. Суть проблемы: редирект из апача работает только со ссылками http (редирект идет на https) и не работает из https ссылок

Comment: Спасибо большое. Уже буду решать это с тех. поддержкой.